# Confusion about definition of faithful group action.

Tags: group-theory, definition, group-actions

Here are some excerpts from my lecture note:

> - An action from a group $G$ to a set $X$ is a homomorphism $\alpha: G \to \text{Sym}(X)$, where $\text{Sym}(X)$ is the group of bijections $X \to X$.
> - Equivalently, an action $\alpha$ of $G$ on $X$ can be viewed as a map $G \times X \to X$, which we usually write as $(g,x) \mapsto g \cdot x := \alpha_g(x) \in X$.
> - An action $\alpha$ is called faithful if it is injective.
> - The action of left translation of a group $G$ on itself is defined as $L_g(h) = gh$, for some fixed $g \in G$. This action is faithful.

Am I correct to assume that the statement that $L_g$ is faithful is vacuously true, since we are restricting the domain of the action to just one element $g$? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's $L$ that is faithful, not $L_g$.

That each $L_g$ is a bijection is indeed obvious. To show $L$ is faithful you need to show that $L_g \ne L_h$ when $g \ne h$.

That is not hard.

Comment: Take $G$ to be $(\mathbb{Z},+)$. Here left translation would be $L_n(h) = n + h$. I can see how, by the first definition, $L$ is faithful, as $L(n_1)$ and $L(n_2)$ are two different bijections in $\text{Sym}(\mathbb{Z})$, for $n_1 \neq n_2$. But, by the second definition, this might not hold, since, for example, both $(2,1)$ and $(1,2)$ are mapped to $3$. What am I missing?

Comment: The fact that $L_2(1) = L_1(2)$ does not mean that the functions $L_1$ and $L_2$ (each of which is injective) are the same function. The definition does not say that the map from $G \times X$ to $X$ is injective. That map is not named in the text you quote . It's not the map $\alpha$,

Comment: Let $F$ be that map $G \times X \to X$. Are you saying that injectivity of $\alpha$ does not imply injectivity of $F$? And if so, when looking at injectivity of $\alpha$, we need to go by the first definition?

Comment: @ensbana, $F$ is faithful $\stackrel{(def.)}{\iff} \alpha$ is injective.

Comment: That's exactly what I am saying. $F$ can't be injective (for a group with more than one element) because you will always have $F(a,e) = F(e,a) = a$. If you want to write the definition of "faithful" in terms of $F$ you first define the functions $F(g, \cdot)$ and then postulate that those functions are different from one another.